# Convert range to timestamp in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column in a pandas data frame that goes from 0 to 172800000 in steps of 10. I would like to convert into datetime stamp with a specified date, beginning at midnight of that day.

So, suppose,

```
time = np.arange(0,172800000, 10)
```

I would like to convert this in the following format:

```
YYYY-MM-DD: HH:MM:SS.XXX
```

The starting date should be **2016-09-20**.

Here's what I have done:

```
# Create a dummy frame as an example: 
test = pd.DataFrame()
time = np.arange(0, 172800000, 10)
test['TIME'] = time
data = np.random.randint(0, 1000, size=len(time))
test['DATA'] = data

# Convert time to datetime:
test['TIME'] = pd.to_datetime(test['TIME'], unit='ms')
```

If I check the head of the data frame, I get the following:

```
             TIME           DATA
0   1970-01-01 00:00:00.000 681
1   1970-01-01 00:00:00.010 986
2   1970-01-01 00:00:00.020 957
3   1970-01-01 00:00:00.030 422
4   1970-01-01 00:00:00.040 319
```

How do I get the year, month, and day to start on 2016, 09, 20 and not 1970?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
test['TIME'] = pd.to_datetime('2016-09-20') + pd.to_timedelta(time, 'ms')
```

Comment: Thank you. I like this one because it is really succinct! I actually have 10 days worth of data in milliseconds. So creating a data frame and then adding my original data frame may take too much memory and slow down the process.

Answer (score 4):

This is the raison d'ȇtre for `pandas.date_range()`:

```
import pandas as pd

test = pd.DataFrame({'TIME': pd.date_range(start='2016-09-20',
                                           freq='10ms', periods=20)})
print(test)
```

Output:

```
                      TIME
0  2016-09-20 00:00:00.000
1  2016-09-20 00:00:00.010
2  2016-09-20 00:00:00.020
3  2016-09-20 00:00:00.030
4  2016-09-20 00:00:00.040
5  2016-09-20 00:00:00.050
6  2016-09-20 00:00:00.060
7  2016-09-20 00:00:00.070
8  2016-09-20 00:00:00.080
9  2016-09-20 00:00:00.090
10 2016-09-20 00:00:00.100
11 2016-09-20 00:00:00.110
12 2016-09-20 00:00:00.120
13 2016-09-20 00:00:00.130
14 2016-09-20 00:00:00.140
15 2016-09-20 00:00:00.150
16 2016-09-20 00:00:00.160
17 2016-09-20 00:00:00.170
18 2016-09-20 00:00:00.180
19 2016-09-20 00:00:00.190
```

(Substitute `periods=20` for `periods=172800000`)

Comment: I like this one too.